# puppetlab java module install problems

Tags: python, puppet

i want to install the puppetlab/java module into the client-server architecture using the puppermaster and puppet agent.
on server side i download java module and create node in site.pp file
My node content

```
node 'test_java'{
    include activemq
    include stdlib
    include java
}
```

in last java include gives error at client side executing the following command.

```
puppet agent --test --trace
```

Error code:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class java for test_java on node test_java
```

i think the problem is some parameter needed by the java class after looking into the init.pp file.like as follows.

```
class java(
  $distribution = 'jdk',
  $version      = 'present'
) {

  validate_re($distribution, '^jdk$|^jre$|^java.*$')
  validate_re($version, 'installed|^[._0-9a-zA-Z:-]+$')

  anchor { 'java::begin': }
  anchor { 'java::end': }

  case $::osfamily {

    'RedHat': {

      class { 'java::package_redhat':
        version      => $version,
        distribution => $distribution,
        require      => Anchor['java::begin'],
        before       => Anchor['java::end'],
      }

    }
    ........
    ........
```

i am not understand what parameter i have to pass and how in node?

Comment: This has absolutely *nothing* to do with Pascal. Please tag your questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are what is listed between the `()` in the class definition. For instance, that class takes the parameters `$distribution` and `$version`.

You would provide those in your site.pp like this:

```
class{"java":
    distribution => YOUR DISTRIBUTION,
    version      => YOUR VERSION
}
```

You'll see in that example though, they already have sensible defaults. Not to mention the error would not be that the class cannot be found ,it would be that a required parameter was not provided.

Moving on to your actual problem... Puppet cannot find the class in it's path. Do you know that the `activemq` and `stdlib` classes are found? Can you comment out the `include java` and see if the other classes load correctly? If so, then make sure the `java` class is installed in the same directory as those. If not, you'll need to look into how to define the [modulepath](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#modulepath) on the puppetmaster.

Comment: i have tryed with this one not i am getting.
Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError

Comment: Which part did you try? Removing the java include to see if it's just that module vs all modules?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been on vacation. Anyhow, can you post your puppetmaster's module path? That will help track down where it's looking for the class.